# Ceramic capacitor blow out

Tags: capacitor, short-circuit, repair

I run a SOHO system.  Yesterday, a major fault caused my system to stop working.

General inspection of the motherboard revealed nothing.

Test bedding the board produced a flare in one of the capacitors, which oddly resulted in a full working board.

My question is of course why the faulty capacitors blown out state resulted in a working board.

Should I get it replaced?

Comment: It was probably a Tantalum capacitor, not ceramic. These often fail short then explode when more (unlimited) current is applied.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the capacitor was shorted and the test bed had enough current capacity to blow the short circuit. Once the capacitor became open, the board started working again.

The capacitor is probably not critical to the operation of the board (since you say that the board works), but, of course, it's better to replace it.

Also, you should think why the fault happened in the first place, as it could happen again as soon as you replace the capacitor.

Comment: Yes thanks for that, it's a 24hr operational server and I'm just wondering if it's reached it's operational time limit, 5yrs. You're right of course replacing the capacitor is a must although I feel 'If it isn't broke'  I'm going to look into getting it done at a price rather than by myself as I'm rather rubbish at soldering such minute capacitors... Thanx for the reply!

Comment: @JimDonnellon I would expect the motherboard to last longer much longer. I think things that typically need replacing are mechanical parts, like fans or HDDs. Whether to replace the board is up to you. If it's for business, it may be more cost effective to replace.